# C programming basic shell

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am trying to write a simple shell which accepts command line input and execute it as a background task.

How do I allow the child process to report to the parent process once it is completed, like the Bash shell?

```
user@user-desktop:~$ sleep 10 &
[1] 3729
user@user-desktop:~$ sleep 2 &
[2] 3730
user@user-desktop:~$ 
[1]-  Done                    sleep 10
[2]+  Done                    sleep 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is your homework, I won't give you full answer.

The [GNU Glibc manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Implementing-a-Shell.html#Implementing-a-Shell) list the requirnment for job control shell. Let's see if you can understand it.

Basically:

- you have to change the control terminal to make jobs run in background
- you have to handle `SIGCHLD` (or `wait`) to monitor jobs

Ask again after you have read it.

Comment: hi, I have read http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Launching-Jobs.html#Launching-Jobs. But I still don't have any idea in implementing the control terminal you are mentioning. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: @liangtech,  click the "next" link. It's the "tcsetpgrp" in 27.6.4 Foreground and Background

Answer (score 0):

You need to code a signal handler that handles the SIGCHLD (sometimes named SIGCLD) signal which is sent to parent processes when a child terminates.

Comment: And do what in the signal handler ?

Comment: I understand I can implement a signal handler to "listen" for SIGCHLD when the child process terminates it will send a SIGCHLD signal.

But what is the [2]+ beside the command
  [2]+  Done                    sleep 2

Comment: @liangteh: The "done" message is not written by the child - it's the parent process (the shell) that writes out that one of the child processes has terminated. ---

Comment: @ktf how about [1] and [2] what are they suppose to represent?

Comment: @liangteh Its the job number. all processes that run in the background of a shell are numbered.  with the command 'fg 1' you can get the job 1 to the foreground again.

Comment: Try also 'jobs' after you run the sleeps. You'll see the list of jobs with their numbers and state.